# Geometry optimization: energy not lowered in every cycle

Tags: computational-chemistry

I am performing geometry optimizations of an enzyme active site, covalently bonded to a substrate. I have a total of 122 atoms, of which 7 are fixed in space during the optimizations. I am using ORCA to perform D3-B3LYP/6-31+g(d,p) optimizations with the conductor-like polarizable continuum model (epsilon=4).

For certain starting geometries, I notice the energy fluctuates a lot during the geometry cycles, decreasing and increasing. With good geometry convergence I should expect the energy to be lowered in each cycle, but I do not see this. My model should be very flexible, with a lot of shallow energy minima. Could too big step sizes accidentally lead my optimization out of one minimum region and into another, making it difficult to converge the calculation?

Or, more generally, which factors could lead to such a convergence behavior, and are there any common strategies to improve geometry convergence?

Comment: This depends a lot on the algorithm you use for the geometry optimization. For instance, using a quasi-Newton scheme, one is not guaranteed smooth convergence, but it will usually get to the desired minimum. Following both gradients or eigenvectors can also lead to this oscillation because you may be following the gradient or eigenvector in one direction, when the ordering of these switches, so one starts making quite different changes to the geometry that sometime leads to increased energy. It is certainly possible though that too large of step sizes can be a problem with very shallow minima.